# How to resolve /hibernate.cfg.xml not found exception when Session factory create?

Tags: java, hibernate, jbossfuse

I'm working on a JBoss fuse project and I was able to resolve most of the dependency issues related to integration with hibernate on JBoss fuse 6.3 version. But Unfortunately when the program try to create hibernate session it gives following exception saying that it could not able to find the `/hibernate.cfg.xml`  file. Following figure shows my project structure. Project contain the hibernate.cfg.xml file inside the resources folder.

[image]

Exception on the point application try to create the session

```
      JBossFuse:karaf@root> SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
```

Whole exception is similar to below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.demo.activemq.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)[388:DemoActiveMq1:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
at com.demo.activemq.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)[388:DemoActiveMq1:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
at com.demo.activemq.OrderProcessor.process(OrderProcessor.java:18)[388:DemoActiveMq1:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63)
... 45 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)[346:org.hibernate.core:4.2.22.Final-redhat-1]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2090)[346:org.hibernate.core:4.2.22.Final-redhat-1]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2071)[346:org.hibernate.core:4.2.22.Final-redhat-1]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2051)[346:org.hibernate.core:4.2.22.Final-redhat-1]
at com.demo.activemq.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)[388:DemoActiveMq1:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
... 48 more
```

Below is my HibernateUtil.java content and this is the line 13 of that file `return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();`

```
package com.demo.activemq;


import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    // Close caches and connection pools
    getSessionFactory().close();
}

}
```

Following are the dependencies of my pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.17.0.redhat-630187</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
  <version>2.17.0.redhat-630187</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
  <version>2.17.0.redhat-630187</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.11</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.22.Final-redhat-1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-dbcp</artifactId>
  <version>1.4_3</version>
</dependency>
```

Have any one experienced this kind of issue ? How can I resolve this issue ? please be kind enough to provide feedback about this

Comment: Hello. First of all, do you have `hibernate.cfg.xml` file ? If you do, where is `hibernate.cfg.xml` located in your project ?

Comment: I have added it on src/main/resources folder. I have updated the question with project structure .

Comment: try this by providing full path of cfg file, Configuration().configure("./com/eclear/cfg/xml/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

Answer (score 0):

`new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory()` without any method argument is deprecated, you are getting exception because of that.

Please modify your `buildSessionFactory()` method as follows:

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        Configuration configure = new Configuration();
        return configure.buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegisteryBuilder
                                  .applySettings(configure.getProperties())
                                  .build());
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

If face any issue please let me know in comments.

Comment: I got an Compilation error saying can not find " StandardServiceRegisteryBuilder" Is it required additional jars ?

Comment: Which jars you have added could you please edit the question with pom.xml file?

Comment: Which version of hibernate you are using?

Comment: Your hibernate version should be 4.x above like 4.3

Comment: I'm using 4.2.22.Final-redhat-1 version since it should match with JBoss fuse version. I have added the dependencies in to question.

Answer (score 0):

`Hibernate 4.x` introduced `ServiceRegistry`. Your code follows `Hibernate 3.x` standards. And `new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory()` was valid in `Hibernate 3.x`. Since you are using `Hibernate 4.x` and `hibernate.cfg.xml`, your code for creating `SessionFactory` should be something like this:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
              .applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Because, if you check the Hibernate documentation for `configure()` method in `Configuration` class, it says:

> Use the mappings and properties specified in an application resource
>   named hibernate.cfg.xml.

And if you are using `hibernate.properties` file, you code for creating a `configuration` object should be like:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
```